# How can I properly sort and paginate queries with multiple orderBy clauses?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I would like to show a list of the most popular posts in the past 24 hours, sorted by score. This is a paginated list, so it involves the `startAfter` and `limit` fn's. Initially I tried:

```
query(
  collection(db, "posts"),
  where("community", "==", community),
  where("timeCreated", ">=", Timestamp.fromDate(yesterday)),
  orderBy("countScore", "desc"),
  startAfter(lastDoc),
  limit(amount)
)
```

But that highlighted a limitation I didn't previously read into:

> Uncaught (in promise) FirebaseError: Invalid query. You have a where filter with an inequality (<, <=, !=, not-in, >, or >=) on field 'timeCreated' and so you must also use 'timeCreated' as your first argument to orderBy(), but your first orderBy() is on field 'countScore' instead.

To fix this error I could add an `orderBy("timeCreated")` fn, but when I do that the result set ends up not being ordered by score. Is there a way of building a query to satisfy the requirement? If not, what could an alternative solution be? Could I use a composite key on a document from `posts` somehow? Ideally I would avoid turning to Cloud Functions or separate collections to keep track of the intended order.

Answer (score 0):

Once you add the `orderBy("timeCreated")`, the results will be ordered on `timeCreated` first and the value of `countScore` will only be used in cases where documents have the same `timeCreated`.

There is no way to change this behavior of a query in Firestore. You will have to reorder the results on the client.

Comment: Seems like this is impossible to paginate correctly without fetching the entire result set first.

Comment: Consider using something similar but more flexible than FireBase: MongoDB, if you have the time.

Otherwise: How big is the entire result set? If less than 1-2 MiB  (the size of a high-res image nowadays) it wouldn't have such a large impact to download it once and then sort in the client. In fact after the initial download  the user would consider the sorting super-speedy since it is done on the client.)